# Travis CI no output in after success script

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I have a public Travis CI build for this repository: https://github.com/blacksonic/boar
The problem is that i use a node js script in the after_success part and it appears that it runs it but has no output although it has a single line of `console.log`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some tests on a [sample project](https://github.com/cotsog/travis-ios-test) I have and it seems to work for me.

One thing I'm wondering is if you expanded the logs of the `after_success` step by clicking on the little triangle in the left margin of the log window.

Here is a picture to clarify what I mean:

[image]

Comment: yes it only unfolds if u click that small button, found it some days ago :) i was just in a hurry