# How to print to console in Travis CI

Tags: console, echo, travis-ci

I'm trying to print some information using `echo` in my `.travis.yml` file, but I don't see anything in the log.

**My `.travis.yml` file:**

```
before_install:
  - echo $TRAVIS_COMMIT
  - echo $TRAVIS_TAG
  - echo $TRAVIS_BRANCH
  - echo $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
  - echo $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG
```

**My output:**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Similarly to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31121406/5477656), you have to click the arrow on the left to see the output.

Check out this answer from the other question: [image: useful image from the other answer]

Comment: Adding only links is not good for readers, you can add your idea.

Comment: What to do when there is no arrow to click?

Comment: @jww I think that means there's no collapsed output. If you expect a line to have more output, maybe refresh the page and try again.

Answer (score 5):

Travis CI collapses the output for each phase except for the `script` phase.

If you print to the console with `echo` in the `script` phase, your output will be displayed.

If you print to the console in any other phase, you will need to expand the output for that phase to see your content.

---

*Using this `.travis.yml` config:*

```
script:
  - echo $TRAVIS_COMMIT
  - echo $TRAVIS_TAG
  - echo $TRAVIS_BRANCH
  - echo $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
  - echo $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG
```

*Yields this output:*

[image]